# error installing xapian core gem

Tags: ruby, xapian

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

```
ERROR:  Error installing xapian-core:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

rake1.8 RUBYARCHDIR=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/lib RUBYLIBDIR=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/lib
sh: rake1.8: not found
```

Gem files will remain installed in `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1` for inspection.
Results logged to `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/gem_make.out`

Here is the gem makeout file:

```
rake1.8 RUBYARCHDIR=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/lib RUBYLIBDIR=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/lib
sh: rake1.8: not found
```